# MSSQL Join to put rows into columns column variable as column name

Tags: sql-server, database-design, t-sql, join, query

I have two tables

**TABLE 1**

| PRODUCTID | TITLE |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | Product1 |
| 002 | Product2 |

**TABLE 2**

| ID | PRODUCTID | VARNAME | VARVALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | url | https://... |
| 2 | 001 | length | 30m |
| 3 | 001 | somethingelse | somevalue |

I am trying to make a dynamic pivot thar returns all the records of table 1 and the records of table 2 but as columns with column name the column variable.

| PRODUCTID | TITLE | url | length | somethingelse |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Product1 | https://... | 30m | somevalue |
| 002 | Product2 | null | null | null |

Comment: Have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74232389/12930883)
, it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to use dynamic SQL for this**

```sql
DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max) = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(VARNAME), ',')
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT VARNAME FROM Table2
    ) t
);

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT t1.PRODUCTID, t1.TITLE, t2.VARNAME, t2.VARVALUE
    FROM Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.PRODUCTID = t1.PRODUCTID
) t
PIVOT (
    MAX(VARVALUE) FOR VARNAME IN (
        ' + @cols + '
    )
) pvt;
';

PRINT @sql;  -- for testing

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=29fe5ec6df6491dc3cb04914ff2e0725)

If you are on a version of SQL Server earlier than 2017 then you must use the `FOR XML` method to aggregate the columns